# How can I handle overflow on nav items?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I'm making a web page, and have a bunch of nav items, like this:

```
Home About Contact Help Something Something-Else Another
```

And based on the browser width, I'd like to have any items that can't fit to be put in a dropdown, like this:

**Closed:**

```
Home About Contact Help ...
```

**Open:**

```
Home About Contact Help ... 
                 --------^-------------
                 |     Something      | 
                 |   Something-Else   |
                 |      Another       |
                 ----------------------
```

Is there an easy way of doing that?

Comment: Depends on how smart you need it to be. Do you need it to fit in *all* browser widths? Or predefined ones?

Comment: do it with css and jquery

Comment: @Populus: All widths. Such that it would dynamically put nav items in the dropdown, depending on the browser width.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it all with JS:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
  //Get the window width
  var winWidth = window.width;
  var navItemsWidth = 0; //you'll use this in a minute...
  var extraNavItems = []; //you'll use this in a minute...

  //Then iterate through each nav
  var navItems = document.getElementsByClassName('navItem');
  for (var i = 0; i < navItems.length; i++) {
    //Check the width of each item and compare to win width
    navItemsWidth += navItems[i].innerWidth;
    //if the width is greater than screen width...
    if(navItemsWidth > winWidth) {
       //add Items to an array
       extraNavItems.push(navItems[i]);
       //or you could add them to your drop down here...
    } else {
       //if you are still under winWidth add them to your navBar
       document.getElementById('navBar').html += navItems[i];
    }
  }
};
```

Or you could also look into CSS media queries:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries